# Using An Alias in a Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, join, group-by, alias

I know you cannot use an alias in a *group by* since it is processed before the `SELECT` statement. But is there any type of performance hit if I nest my original `SELECT` statement in a sub-query?

It makes it easier to read, at least for me, but I'm more concerned with performance.

My original query is:

```
SELECT 
    Rec.Description [CO_Desc], 
    EM.Description [EM_Desc], 
    ISNULL(EM.UnitCost, '0') * DPaCT.ProcedureProjection [Proj_Cost],     
    ISNULL(EM.UnitCost, '0') * DPaCt.ProceduresPerformed [Act_Cost]
FROM 
    rpt_DriveMaster DM
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    rpt_Accounts Acct ON DM.AccountID = Acct.AccountID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    IDViewRecruiters Rec ON Acct.RecruiterID = Rec.CodeID
INNER JOIN 
    rpt_CenterDetail CD ON DM.CenterID = CD.CenterID
INNER JOIN 
    IDViewCollectionOp CO ON CD.CenterID = CO.CodeID
INNER JOIN 
    IDViewRegion Reg ON CD.Region = Reg.CodeID
INNER JOIN 
    IDViewOrgCenter Org ON CD.OrgCenter = Org.CodeID
INNER JOIN 
    IDViewOrgSubCenter Sub ON CD.OrgSubCenter = Sub.CodeID
INNER JOIN 
    rpt_DriveStatusDef DrStat ON DM.StatusID = DrStat.StatusID
INNER JOIN 
    DriveProjectionandCollectedTotals DPaCT ON DM.DriveID = DPaCT.DriveID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    EquipmentDetail ED ON DM.DriveID = ED.DriveID
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
    EquipmentMaster EM ON ED.EquipmentId = EM.EquipmentID
WHERE 
    DM.StatusID <> 5 AND 
    DM.FromDateTime BETWEEN '02/01/2014' AND '02/28/2014' AND
    CO.CodeID IN (106,107,108,110)
GROUP BY 
    Rec.Description, 
    EM.Description, 
    ISNULL(EM.UnitCost, '0') * DPaCT.ProcedureProjection,  
    ISNULL(EM.UnitCost, '0') * DPaCt.ProceduresPerformed
```

But I did not like the way the `GROUP BY` read, so I have changed the query to:

```
SELECT 
    A.Rec_Desc, 
    A.EM_Desc, 
    A.Proj_Cost, 
    A.Act_Cost
FROM
(
    SELECT
        Rec.Description [Rec_Desc], 
        EM.Description [EM_Desc],
        ISNULL(EM.UnitCost, '0') * DPaCT.ProcedureProjection [Proj_Cost], 
        ISNULL(EM.UnitCost, '0')  *DPaCt.ProceduresPerformed [Act_Cost]
    FROM 
        rpt_DriveMaster DM
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        rpt_Accounts Acct ON DM.AccountID = Acct.AccountID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        IDViewRecruiters Rec ON Acct.RecruiterID = Rec.CodeID
    INNER JOIN 
        rpt_CenterDetail CD ON DM.CenterID = CD.CenterID
    INNER JOIN 
        IDViewCollectionOp CO ON CD.CenterID = CO.CodeID
    INNER JOIN 
        IDViewRegion Reg ON CD.Region = Reg.CodeID
    INNER JOIN 
        IDViewOrgCenter Org ON CD.OrgCenter = Org.CodeID
    INNER JOIN 
        IDViewOrgSubCenter Sub ON CD.OrgSubCenter = Sub.CodeID
    INNER JOIN 
        rpt_DriveStatusDef DrStat ON DM.StatusID = DrStat.StatusID
    INNER JOIN 
        DriveProjectionandCollectedTotals DPaCT ON DM.DriveID = DPaCT.DriveID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        EquipmentDetail ED ON DM.DriveID = ED.DriveID
    LEFT OUTER JOIN 
        EquipmentMaster EM ON ED.EquipmentId = EM.EquipmentID
    WHERE
        DM.StatusID <> 5 AND 
        DM.FromDateTime BETWEEN '02/01/2014' AND '02/28/2014' AND
        CO.CodeID IN (106,107,108,110)) AS A
    GROUP BY 
        A.Rec_Desc, 
        A.EM_Desc, 
        A.Proj_Cost, 
        A.Act_Cost
```

Am I looking at any real difference in the query performance?

Comment: Why do you need `GROUP BY` to begin with? There's no aggregation in you query. You can use `SELECT DISTINCT` for the same result

Comment: And by the way, your `ISNULL` may return a char. SQL Server will convert it to an int for you, but it's bad form.

Comment: Thanks Zoff, I actually was working up to a sum() and forgot to include that in my original post. Which is bad form. And I changed my ISNULL to remove the ' ' around the 0.

Comment: Compare the execution plans, that should give you an indication